# How to read or write file as getExternalStorageDirectory is deprecated in API 29?

Tags: java, android, android-10.0

I am learning android development and i am facing some problem to read getExternalStorageDirectory in java, I have read https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment but can't understand, can someone help me with example code in java.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(java.lang.String)) you can see:

> `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(String type)`
>
> *This method was deprecated in API level 29. To improve user privacy, direct access to shared/external storage devices is deprecated. When
>   an app targets Build.VERSION_CODES.Q, the path returned from this
>   method is no longer directly accessible to apps. Apps can continue to
>   access content stored on shared/external storage by migrating to
>   alternatives such as  **Context#getExternalFilesDir(String),
>   MediaStore, or Intent#ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT.***

Pass nothing as parameter to this function to get your directory as a `File` object :

`context.getExternalFilesDir();`

Here "Context" is an object which is obtained by `this.getContext();`

`this` is the current object of the Activity. Do check the scope carefully while using it.

**Important**

To access the Internal storage, `Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and/or `Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` are required in the file [AndroidManifest.xml](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro).

Optional information:

1. Usually the internal storage has the path
   /sdcard/ on Android devices. It's not a real path but a [symlink](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link).
2. It's confusing but "external sdcard" in Android acutally means the Internal device storage and not the external ejectable out-of-the-device memory card storage.
   Also note that the real external sdcard cannot be fully access
3. [Activity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) class extends the [Context](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) class  That's why we can get the context from it.

Comment: Be warned that the path returned by this method will be deleted when the app is uninstalled. It is not going to provide the same location that `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` did.

Answer (score 6):

**Updated**

> From Android 11, it won't allow creating folder/file in the root directory but, we can still manage folder separation with help of the public directory (It will show a deprecated warning but it will work)

```
fun getAbsolutePath(context: Context): File {
    return File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "{YOUR_FOLDER_NAME}"))
}
```

Now, create the file with common directory path

```
val file = File(getAbsolutePath(requireContext()), "FILENAME.EXTENSION")
```

**Older**

> Use this static method.
> Currently I don't find any legal way to do this.
> So, I was made this static method to get root or getAbsolutePath file path.

```
public static File getAbsoluteDir(Context ctx, String optionalPath) {
        String rootPath;
        if (optionalPath != null && !optionalPath.equals("")) {
            rootPath = ctx.getExternalFilesDir(optionalPath).getAbsolutePath();
        } else {
            rootPath = ctx.getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath();
        }
        // extraPortion is extra part of file path
        String extraPortion = "Android/data/" + BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID
                + File.separator + "files" + File.separator;
        // Remove extraPortion
        rootPath = rootPath.replace(extraPortion, "");
        return new File(rootPath);
    }
```

Comment: Static path is always a bad solution since Android is too fragmented, your manufacturer might have a different directory path. Do not use this

Comment: It's common for all devices. you can check this.

Comment: `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()` answers 100 other threads with the question of "how to access public DCIM directory (for instance) for saving files". Rest of the answers are for getting the app's internal directory (DCIM for example) which could not be viewed by gallery.

Answer (score 1):

Use `getExternalFilesDir()`, `getExternalCacheDir()`, or `getExternalMediaDirs()`
(methods on Context) instead of `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`

```
String root = mContext.getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath();
File myDir = new File(root + "/" + mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name) + "_share");
    myDir.mkdirs();
```

Answer (score 0):

In 2022, `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory` and `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory` are [undeprecated](https://cs.android.com/android/_/android/platform/frameworks/base/+/9f77f7f31b2427d22bf77c0a0c1b8cf9294c65ff?hl=ko).
They had been marked as *deprecated* from API 29 ~ 31, but not above.